# Why does the selected attribute work for each ng-container?

Tags: angular

I have 2 ng-containers. When I am in one view, I want "My Appointments" selected in the options dropdown when navigating to that view. In the other view, I want "Active" selected in the options dropdown.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div class="row" [@mainAnimation]>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h3 *ngIf="ticketId!=0" class="my-title">{{'Appointments for ticket #' +ticketId}}</h3>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pl-3">
                                <span style="font-size:115%;vertical-align:text-bottom;">
                                  <ng-container *ngIf="ticketId==0">
                                    <select class="dark-text" id="showActive" [(ngModel)]="ctx.showActive"
                                    (change)="load()">
                                        <option selected [ngValue]="2">My Appointments</option>
                                        <option [ngValue]="1">Active</option>
                                        <option [ngValue]="0">Inactive</option>
                                  </select>
                                  </ng-container>
                                  <ng-container *ngIf="ticketId!=0">
                                    <select class="dark-text" id="showActive" [(ngModel)]="ctx.showActive"
                                    (change)="load()">
                                    <option *ngIf="ticketId==0" [ngValue]="2">My Appointments</option>
                                        <option selected [ngValue]="1">Active</option>
                                        <option [ngValue]="0">Inactive</option>
                                  </select>
                                  </ng-container>

                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;{{totalCount}} matching records
                                </span>
                            </td>
```

As you can see in the h3 I have a ticketId. When the ticketId is not 0, I want it to show in that view. That html should also display with the second containter where i have *ngIf="ticketId!=0". It works just fine. But in the other view, "Active" still is selected as default from dropdown instead of "My Appointments."

[image: view]

How do I get "My appointments" to show default as selected?

Relavent .ts code

```
export class AppointmentsComponent extends ComponentCanDeactivate implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  faSort=faSort; faCaretSquareUp=faCaretSquareUp; faCaretSquareDown=faCaretSquareDown; faMinusCircle=faMinusCircle;
  ctx: MyContext; entries: IAppointmentView1[]=[]; recurranceTypes: IRecurranceType[]=[];
  wheelDbr=new MyDebouncer(100); totalCount=0; debouncer=new MyDebouncer(750); 

  @Input() ticketId = 0;
  @ViewChild('actionMenu') actionMenu: ActionMenuComponent;

  constructor(private globals: GlobalsService,private server: ServerService,private router: Router, private modalService: NgbModal, private datepipe: DatePipe) {
    super(); this.ctx=new MyContext(this.globals);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initPageSize(); this.load();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    try { this.ctx.save(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }
    try { this.modalService.dismissAll(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }
  }

  canDeactivate(): boolean { return !this.modalService.hasOpenModals(); }

  load() {
    if(this.ticketId != 0) {
       this.server.getAppointmentsForTicket(this.ticketId, this.ctx.showActive,this.ctx.currPage,this.ctx.pageSize,this.ctx.sort_str,this.ctx.sort_dir,
        r=> { this.entries = r.AppointmentsView; this.totalCount=r.TotalMatchingCount; }); 
    } else {
      this.server.getAppointmentsView1(this.globals.currentUser.id,this.ctx.showActive,this.ctx.currPage,this.ctx.pageSize,this.ctx.sort_str,this.ctx.sort_dir,this.ctx.filter_word,
      r=> { this.entries = r.AppointmentsView; this.totalCount=r.TotalMatchingCount; });
       
    }
      this.server.getRecurranceTypes(r=>this.recurranceTypes=r);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `[(ngModel)]="ctx.showActive"` binding would override your html selected attribute on the options. Also I'm not sure it's a good idea to have two controls with the same id.